# Identificador no Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, apache, fila

Estou tentando integrar um consumidor à uma fila que utiliza o message broker Apache ActiveMQ. No entanto, para consumir essas filas é preciso configurar um identificador, usuário e senha. Não consigo setar esse identificador, o código que estou usando é este:

```
    using Apache.NMS.Util;
    using System;
    using System.Threading;

 namespace Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Test
 {
    public class TestMain
    {
        protected static AutoResetEvent semaphore = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        protected static ITextMessage message = null;
        protected static TimeSpan receiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string conexao = "tcp://IP-DA-FILA-DO-SISTEMA";
        string FILA = "FILA-DO-SISTEMA";

        string identificador = "IDENTIFICADOR-FILA-SISTEMA";

            Uri connecturi = new Uri(conexao);

            Console.WriteLine("Conectando com: " + connecturi);

            IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(connecturi);

            using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection("ADMIN", "ADMIN"))
            using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession())
            {
                IDestination destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, FILA);

                Console.WriteLine("Usando o destino: " + destination);

                using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination))
                //using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(destination))
                {
                    // Iniciar a conexão que as mensagens serão processadas
                    connection.Start();

                    //producer.DeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.Persistent;
                    //producer.RequestTimeout = receiveTimeout;

                    consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(OnMessage);

                    //producer.Send(request);

                    semaphore.WaitOne();
                }
            }
        }


        protected static void OnMessage(IMessage receivedMsg)
        {
            message = receivedMsg as ITextMessage;
            Console.WriteLine(message.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

O usuário, senha e endereço da fila estão corretos (não são esses que estão no código acima), mas não consigo configurar esse identificador que está faltando.

Mensagem de erro:

```
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.BrokerException: 'java.lang.Exception : Invalid consumer for username + password combination!
```

O erro é exibido na seguinte linha:

```
 using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination))
```

Aparentemente a conexão é feita, mas está faltando inserir esse identificador para conseguir criar o consumer.

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro? Você debugou o código? De onde você pegou esse trecho de código?

Comment: Leandro, editei a postagem. Esse trecho de código foi disponibilizado pela apache neste link:https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/examples/nms-simple-asynchronous-consumer-example

Comment: Não está faltando coisa na sua connection string? tipo `activemq:tcp`, assim como na declaração das filas e consumers?

Comment: Já tentei inserindo a string `activemq` antes do endereço tcp e ainda ocorre o mesmo erro. Em alguns teste que realizei, o código activemq que antecede o endereço da conexão é opcional.

Answer (score 0):

Estou respondendo minha própria pergunta para ajudar pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema no futuro.
O erro de conseguir fazer a conexão e não conseguir criar o consumidor é um problema de permissões no message broker. Após resolver esse problema de permissão, foi gerado novos endereços de fila e agora é possível consumir os dados.